# Call c++ function into a PHP code

Tags: php, c++, oop

I have some c++ OOP classes (separated files) , and I want to create objects in PHP code that can call the functions in those classes.. (PHP classes derived from c++ classes).

Because the php is not more than a scripting language, I've got some functions that can only writen by a low level language that has a closed relation with the hardware, (so the c++ is the best choice).

but I want to use those functions(that are without a main function) in a php code, is this possible?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502244/how-can-i-use-c-code-to-interact-with-php

Comment: thank you rlb.usa! I'll see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP classes derived from c++ classes

I don't think there is any way for such close interaction.

You would have to either

- Write a PHP extension in C. Related article: [Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021)
- Write an external program and run it using [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/exec)

Comment: "Write an external program and run it using exec()", But I don't want to write it as a programm, because it has no main function. I only want to call the source code functions, that's all.

Comment: @Simo in that case, you'll have to write a PHP extension. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: As a note: you can always write an extension in C++, and then the parts that interact with PHP can be written in C. Assuming you get all the compiler and linker magic correct, it should be doable (ie: extern C in the C++ code, compile your code with the same GCC version as what compiled the php code... etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest to achieve what you intend to do is to write your C++ functions and export them flat (i.e. not as class). And, using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html), write a facade class that calls those functions. In PHP, you'd simply use your facade class in the OOP manner.