# PHP using c++ extension will be faster?

Tags: php, c++, performance

I'm now building a recommender system(a web site). I want to use the PHP as the script language. The recommender system may do complex matrix computing or something else. Considering the performance,I want to use C++ to do matrix computing or other complex computing. So I need the PHP call C++ function, get the result and do other processing. I know I can use the PHP extension to call C++.
My question is do I need to use C++ or just use PHP to do the complex computing? Is using c++ extension faster than pure PHP?

Comment: Using C++ for advanced computation is often faster.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted off topic???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using a C++ extension for complex calculations will give you a significant speedup over PHP.

Check out these questions for more details to go about doing this:

- [How can I use C++ code to interact with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502244/how-can-i-use-c-code-to-interact-with-php)
- [Extending PHP with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c/1966341)